# OutOfMemoryError in weblogic server

Tags: java, weblogic, out-of-memory

We have changed lot of files and now in production we  are facing OutOfMemoryError in weblogic  10.4.3 server,

From the log we got the following error messages related to outOfMemory Error:

```
1) java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: getNewTla
2) java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: allocLargeObjectOrArray: [C, size 262160 ..
```

But we unable to trace, which code causes outOfMemoryError.

How can we track this down?

Comment: Can you post the Stack trace?

Answer (score 1):

> Please suggest me if anybody have information regarding this.

With a question as general and vague as this, the only things I can suggest are standard approaches to this kind of problem:

- Configure the JVM to take a heap dump when it OOME's, and analyse it with `jhat` or something.
- Examine the stack traces (more) carefully.
- Examine out what you've changed by examining your version control history.  If you are totally stumped, back-out the changesets to the last known working version and reapply them one at a time.  (On your test server ... of course!)
- Run the unit tests / system tests.